# Unable to Verify Entra Application Publisher when hosted on Google Sites

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have an application which has been published to the `Microsoft Store`, and also shows up under the `Microsoft Entra admin center` under the personal applications.

I now wish to verify the application in order to make more changes. In order to make the changes I first need to verify the publisher.

I am presented with the option to host a file with specific contents i.e.

> https://EXAMPLE.COM/.well-known/microsoft-identity-association.json

```
{
  "associatedApplications": [
    {
        "applicationId": "some application id"
    }
  ]
}
```

**My current web site is hosted using Google Sites, and it appears that I am not able to host this ?**

What are the alternatives to get verified. I have added the "domain" Under custom domains, where I had to add specific TXT DNS records. Although the domain is verified, the application is still showing as Unverified.

**Are there any other options, or ways to solve this?**